# Difference between residual deviance in summary() and anova() of negative binomial model

Tags: r, anova, negative-binomial-distribution, deviance

I've been looking at analysis of deviance tables of negative binomial models in R using the `anova()` function and can't work out why the figures for residual deviance don't agree with the figures given in `summary()`.

For example, using the quine dataset in the MASS package, I fit two nested negative binomial models:

```
quine.nb1 <- glm.nb(Days ~ Sex, data = quine)
quine.nb2 <- glm.nb(Days ~ Sex + Age, data = quine)
```

Using`summary(quine.nb1)` I can see that the residual deviance of the model with just sex is 168.22. But when I use `anova(quine.nb2)` to calculate residual deviance as variables are added sequentially, the residual deviance for a model with just sex is 177.98.

```
Analysis of Deviance Table

Model: Negative Binomial(1.1474), link: log

Response: Days

Terms added sequentially (first to last)


     Df Deviance Resid. Df Resid. Dev Pr(>Chi)  
NULL                   145     179.04           
Sex   1   1.0593       144     177.98  0.30337  
Age   3   9.7594       141     168.22  0.02073 *
```

I can't find anything in the documentation that explains why the two numbers are different and Google hasn't helped.

Is there a reason for the two numbers to be different? Is there some factor in the calculation that I'm missing?

Comment: Did you get a warning when you did the anova?

Comment: @mdewey Yes, obviously I get the warning that the test is done without re-estimating theta, but theta isn't enough to explain the difference - if you do the test with correctly estimated thetas by calling `anova(quine.nb1, quine.nb2)` the results are the same as they are in  `anova(quine.nb2)` and still different to what you'd get if you used the residual deviances shown in `summary()`.